# Include external css to Angular library

Tags: css, angular, external

I should import external css file (from npm package) to my custom Angular library. So I don't know how will I do it.

I tried to import it with `@import '~npmpackage/style.min.css`, but when I installed that Angular library to Angular application then I got issue `localhost:4200/~npmpackage/style.min.css` not found.

Answer (score 0):

1. create new scss file in src folder
2. using @import directive import the CSS file from the NPM package

   @import 'package-name/path/to/css/file.css';
3. In Angular library's angular.json file, add the path to the new .scss file to the styles array in the build and test targets.

Comment: CSS file that you want to import is specified in the package.json file of the package. Look for a style property in the package.json file, and note the path to the CSS file

Comment: `@import` is deprecated in new Angular version. Use `@use`.